# Is there a way to create a custom Range type in Postgres that wraps around?

Tags: postgresql

For some context here, I'm looking to create a custom `TIME` Range in Postgres for use with capturing business operating hours in the database.

There's an example in the docs here:

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DEFINING,

which has a nice `subtype_diff` definition and `TIME` range creation script.

However, I would also like to create timeranges such as `['17:00:00', '04:00:00]` (for instance, for businesses that are open late).

I've tried defining different `subtype_diffs` such as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION time_subtype_diff(x time, y time) 
RETURNS float8 AS 'SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH 
        FROM (CASE WHEN (y > x) 
              THEN -(x - y)
        ELSE (x - y) 
        END))' 
LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

Along with the time range example from the docs:

```
CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (subtype = time, subtype_diff = time_subtype_diff);.
```

No matter what kind of `subtype_diff` I try however, I always seem to be blocked by this error:

```
ERROR: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound
```

when I try and create an actual time range:

```
(`SELECT timerange('20:00:00', '08:00:00');`).
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: On a side note, it is quite often practical to store the day of the week along the opening hours (ex: Monday: 8h00-21h00, Saturday: 10h30-15h30, Sunday: closed), in which case you can split the range spanning two days into two records (20h00-midnight; midnight->8h00)

Comment: I'd look into multiranges. That allows you to have something like `{[00:00,04:00],[17:00,24:00)}`.